# Get child element values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get all the href values which lie under `id="categoryName"` using javascript?

```
<div class="makeStyles-categoryBreadscrumb-83" id="categoryName">
    <a href="/">Home </a><a href="/category/shoes.html">Shoes</a><a>Boots &amp; Booties</a>
</div>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("categoryName").innerHTML
```

Comment: using `document.getElementById('categoryName').innerHTML` this you can get html only. what you get ??

Comment: get all href value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.querySelectorAll("parent > child");`

```js
let elements =document.querySelectorAll("#categoryName > a");

elements.forEach((x) => {
console.log(x);
})
```

```html
<div class="makeStyles-categoryBreadscrumb-83" id="categoryName">
  <a href="/">Home </a><a href="/category/shoes.html">Shoes</a><a>Boots &amp; Booties</a>
  <a href="/">Bla </a><a href="/category/shoes.html">Shoes</a><a>Boots &amp; Booties</a>
</div>
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("categoryName > a");
can i use this ?

Comment: yes but categoryName is an id  so you have to select it by using a # before. `#categoryName`

Comment: document.getElementById("categoryName > a ")
Is this ok ?

Comment: No it isn't getElementById is looking for an element by an id. Use querySelectorAll here

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#categoryName > a");`this is how you can use it

Answer (score 0):

You can your result with the help of `querySelectorAll`.

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("#categoryName > a");

x.forEach((x) => {
  if(x.href) {
    console.log(x.href);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="makeStyles-categoryBreadscrumb-83" id="categoryName">
    <a href="/">Home </a><a href="/category/shoes.html">Shoes</a><a>Boots &amp; Booties</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
let x =document.getElementById('parent').children
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  console.log(x.item(i).href)
}
```

Comment: Hey muhammad, welcome to Stack Overflow! Good work providing a possible solution, but try to elaborate on why this solution works, what it does. You can do this by editing your answer.